# MySQL server [Version 5.0.96] installation fails on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion

MySQL Installation fails when installing it on Mac os Mountain Lion.

I don't why this simple installation fails.

The file that I am trying to install is mysql-5.0.96-osx10.5-x86.dmg.

[image: MySQL server Installation Error]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate. Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645038/mysql-the-installation-failed-on-snow-leopard/5651195#5651195

Comment: is this a clean OS Install? do you have the OX Developer Tools installed?

Comment: Developer Tools are also installed on this OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as your installation method instead. It's very well maintained across a lot of core packages for developers.

You start with this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Follow the installation instructions, then:

```
brew install mysql
```

I've had two successful installs with no problems on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I used the above two commands but landed different error while running mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: Do you see anything if you type `ps ax | grep mysqld`? This should list any running mysqld processes. The brew install method doesn't actually start the database for you. I believe to start the database server, you need to type `mysql.server start`.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Usually the reason you can't connect through the mysql.sock file is if the mysqld server isn't actually running.

Comment: On executing ps ax | grep mysqld. It returns one process which is like this "668 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep mysqld". on typing mysql.server start it is not able to recognise it. Any idea to install it .dmg provided by MySQL. People says its the issue with creating user group "_mysql". I wanted it to install it on urgent basis but, still working around with this issue.

Comment: OK mysql is not running. Did you follow the instructions after installing with Hombebrew?  You need to execute something like mysql_install_db --verbose --user=your_user --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp

Comment: [Another resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359131/brew-install-mysql-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 1):

On Mountain Lion you should be using the `64-bit` DMG I had no problem installing MySQL on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Moving ahead I downloaded a new .dmg file which is mysql-5-1.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg.

Now, this seems to be 64 bit version, but no success yet.

So, I think this is not a issue related to version [32 or 64 bit].

Comment: I have installed the same file on MacOS Lion. But, on Mountain Lion it fails. Any one of you have installed on Mountain Lion.